# creating new admin webmin user in shell

Tags: linux, passwords, admin, webmin

Installed `webmin` and want to create a new user non root to login, follow the steps :

1. Edit the file `/etc/webmin/miniserv.users` and add a line for your new user like

   ```
   anubhav:12ZVLjpihs:0
   ```
2. Edit file  `/etc/webmin/webmin.acl` and copy the first line for the root user and paste it in same file , rename root to the new user and save the file, so the file should be like

   ```
   root:access privileges
   anubhav:access privileges
   ```
3. Reset the new user password `/usr/share/webmin/changepass.pl /etc/webmin anubhav mypassword`.
4. Restart `webmin` from `/etc/init.d/webmin restart`
5. Navigate to your `webmin` page and login user new username and password.

Comment: I upvoted, so now you should have enough reputation be able to split it to question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Have a look at this easy step-by-step guide: https://forum.virtualmin.com/t/how-to-access-virtualmin-if-ssh-loging-root-with-ssh-rsa-public-private-key/104923/10

Comment: (centos) If the Restart step is failing, try with:  /etc/webmin/restart

Answer (score 11):

just in addition:
RedHat distribution (i.e. Fedora, CentOS, Gentoo, etc.):

```
/usr/libexec/webmin/changepass.pl /etc/webmin admin newpassword
```

Debian distribution (i.e. Debian, Ubuntu, etc.):

```
/usr/share/webmin/changepass.pl /etc/webmin admin newpassword
```

FreeBSD:

```
/usr/local/lib/webmin/changepass.pl /usr/local/etc/webmin admin newpassword
```

Remember to replace "admin" and "newpassword" with your own details!

Comment: This update existing user's password, does not add new user. You need to add new linux user before this will work.

Comment: Have a look at this easy step-by-step guide: https://forum.virtualmin.com/t/how-to-access-virtualmin-if-ssh-loging-root-with-ssh-rsa-public-private-key/104923/10